# can not display on external display properly

Tags: iphone

I try to display an app in external display, actually, it is a giant Iphone monitor (height is 1.5 m and wild is .5m ) and running into an issue. It is that my app is displayed in landscape mode with height is 320px and wild is 460px. However, in the giant iphone, my app is half of screen. How can I make it fit 1.5m x 0.5 m. Are there any ways to trick an system so that I can display a full screen in gian Iphone monitor even though the height and width of actual iphone is 320 and 460 respectively.
Please help if you have any ideas. All answer are welcomed here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you scale your output appropriately for the external display.  Something like this should get you on your way:

```
// if an external screen is attached it will be in the array of screens
if ( [[UIScreen screens] count] > 1 )
{
    UIScreen *screen2 = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    CGRect screenBounds = screen2.bounds;
    NSLog(@"Should scale external output to fit in %dx%d",
          (int)screenBounds.size.width,
          (int)screenBounds.size.height);
}
```

There's lots of good information in Apple's [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH1-SW2) and the reference for [UIScreen](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html).

I guess it's worth mentioning that you are *very unlikely* to get any UI interaction (touch events, etc) from an external display.  Most displays aren't touch displays and I'm don't believe touch events are even supported on an external display.  So, any configuration of the information displayed on the external display will need to be controlled from the iOS device.